# optional data in the constructor, bad practice?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, typescript

Currently I have a model class that represents a user.
This class has a constructor that takes an object with all user properties, used for example, when creating the user. In this case I instantiate the model passing it the necessary information so it's constructor can do the job, then it will use its own "createUser" method. Fine.

But in some cases, I don't need to pass all those information to the constructor.
For example the model has an "UdpateCustomUserName" method that just need userId in order to instantiate from the db and perform this method and update a single field from a single already existing record in the database.

The way I dealt with this is make the "properties" information needed by the constructor optional, so when I need to call "UdpateCustomUserName" I just pass to the model the ID and I can instantiate and reach this method.

Is this the proper way of doing it ?
Or is it a bad practice to have optional constructor parameters ? In this case i would extract "UdpateCustomUserName" and keep it in the same module but as a standalone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optional parameters is not a bad practice, definitely not, but sometimes the optional parameters may be optional solely because of what the class does.

You arrived at a problem which is a result of a bad design. You are trying to figure out how to ignore certain properties of a model if you don't use them. The problem is, you are mixing responsibilities of classes together and trying to create a class which knows and does many things. That is pretty bad and might cause you troubles later on, because it will be very difficult to reuse the class in a different environment, for example.

Obviously, when you have a class which can do many operations, there will be a situation where one operation will not need everything that the class contains, but is required for other operations.

What you should be after is splitting your current class into several smaller classes, each being responsible for only one thing and make the class do the thing well. You could have a UserModel, which could be an actual representation of a user in your code, you could then have some sort of service, which would accept the user and do an operation on it. Obviously, if the operation required database access, you would need to provide a class acting as the database accessor to the service class as a dependency as well.

I personally would opt for refactoring the monolithic class into several smaller ones, each taking only the dependency (or dependencies) which it really needs.

Comment: Nice answer, because it goes to the bigger picture in which the OP finds themself, and to the appropriateness of the domain abstraction the OP is trying to provide.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I will definitely refactor. I really felt my  code was bad. Some of the task that need to be performed, such as add data into a specific field, might as well be in a function, not necessarily in a class. People always mention class, to the point it seems 'weird' to just have floating function in module files... which in my case would have been the natural way to do things if I had not forced it into the class.

Answer (score 0):

Having optional parameter constructors eliminates the need for multiple constructor overloads.

In Java, there's an entire software pattern for this called the Builder Pattern, which essentially replaces multiple constructors with a fluent interface.  It's an elaborate, overly complex and ultimately unsatisfying pattern; optional constructor parameters is a far better solution.

Comment: It depends on how much arguments your class can have. A UserProfile can become quite big with a lot of optional fields. In those cases builder pattern works better for future compatibility. It also works nicely with collections and varargs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No. It Depends.

**Scenario 1:** You are the sole developer on the project or its your personal project.

*Practices do not matter*. What matters is that it works and its of good quality.

**Scenario 2:** There are muliple people working on this project

*Yes it is a bad practice*. Only required fields must be part of constructor parameters. Either use overloaded constructors or break down the class into multiple ones. Also remember, boring code that the team understands is better than clever code that only one person understands.